# Regex to extract specific urls from <img> tags in an HTML document

Tags: php, html, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract a specific url pattern from the body of some content and replace it with a newly formed url. But I am running into problems with my regex patterns and wanted to see if you could help me.

Here is the code I am testing this with:

```
$body = '<p><img src="/file/637/view" height="540" width="640"></p>';
$pattern = '/src="/file/(0-9)+/view"/';
$pattern = '/src="/file/(.)+/view"/';
$pattern = '/"/file/[0-9]+/view"';
$pattern = '/\<img src="(.)+"(.)+"\>/';

preg_match($pattern, $body, $matches);
```

Now, the last pattern down will grab the entire image tag, which is great, but what I want it to extract all image urls (just the url) that use the "/file/(some number)/view" pattern so that I can form new urls and then do a string replace on them. All of the others fail to find anything when I run print_r on the $matches var.

Obviously the body string represents the content body that I am scanning for this. Any suggestions as to how to get this to work and grab just the image url? This will have to work for situations with multiple images intermingled with lots of other html including anchor tags.

Comment: The real question is, why are you using regex vs. xml parsing?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: @tandu Last time I checked it was cheaper (resource-wise) to run a little regex on a small block of content than to parse the segment of html into an object and then run operations on it and convert it back to html from the object. So unless you have a compelling argument as to how it is more efficient to parse the HTML, modify it, then convert it back I think I will stick with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace `(.)` with `(.*?)` or for your problem, try following

```
$body = '<p><img src="/file/637/view" height="540" width="640"></p>';
$pattern = '/\/file\/([0-9]+)\/view/';


preg_match($pattern, $body, $matches);
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? $pattern = '/src="/file/(.*?)+/view"/';

Comment: Need to escape some slashes (or, preferably, change the delimiters) there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape slashes, I think you have some unescaped slashes there

try this:

```
$body = '<p><img src="/file/637/view" height="540" width="640"></p>';
$pattern = '/<img src="\/file\/([0-9]+)\/view"/'

preg_match($pattern, $body, $matches);

echo ($matches[1]);
```